# Angular2 SystemJs Bundles and Non Bundled js

Tags: format, angular, require, systemjs, bundles

I'm new to SystemJs and Angular2. I am using 3rd party packages, some of which have `bundles/code.js` files and some do not.

The ones that are using `bundles/code.js` I have managed to get working.

I include `<script src=foo/bundles/code.js>` and am then able to `import * from 'code/foo'` inside my `ts` files.

This all makes sense to me as the `bundles/code.js` has something like `System.registerDynamic("code/foo",...)` and so the `import` knows what `code/foo` is (This is my understanding of it)

I have come across a package that does not use bundles. The `.js` file I need to load looks like this:

```
// ./vendor/ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload.js

function __export(m) {
    for (var p in m) if (!exports.hasOwnProperty(p)) exports[p] = m[p];
}
__export(require('./components/file-upload/file-select'));
__export(require('./components/file-upload/file-drop'));
__export(require('./components/file-upload/file-uploader'));
var file_select_2 = require('./components/file-upload/file-select');
var file_drop_2 = require('./components/file-upload/file-drop');
exports.FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTIVES = [file_select_2.FileSelect, file_drop_2.FileDrop];
//# sourceMappingURL=ng2-file-upload.js.map
```

I realize this is not in `System` format. I have tried the following in my `index.html`:

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        'js': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        }
    },
    meta: {
       'vendor/ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload.js' : {
            format: 'cjs', // I have also tried 'amd' and 'global'
            defaultExtension: 'js'
       }
    }
});
```

I have also tried

```
System.config({
    packages: {
        'js': {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
       'vendor/ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload.js' : {
            format: 'cjs', // I have also tried 'amd' and 'global'
            defaultExtension: 'js'
       }
    }
});
```

No matter what I do I end up with the following error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

#### I have 2 questions:

- How do I load `ng2-file-upload.js`?
- How would I go about creating a `bundle` for this package? (The package contains all `.ts` and `.d.ts` files when running `npm install`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This all makes sense to me as the bundles/code.js has something like System.registerDynamic("code/foo",...) and so the import knows what code/foo is (This is my understanding of it)

You are correct, when you compile your code as system modules, it is safe to load them with script tag, assuming `SystemJS` is loaded. You can test this with:

```
  <script async src="~/system.src.js"></script>
```

Loading system.js asynchronously will give:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined

Same is with `commonjs` modules, so if you don't use `RequireJS` loader, don't load them via script tag. Instead you should use `SystemJS` to load `commonjs` modules:

```
  System.import("vendor/ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload.js")
    .then(function() {
       System.import("/static/scripts/bootstrap.js");
    }, console.error.bind(console));
```

`ng2-file-upload.js` should already be a bundle, hence you're loading it this way. If it's not, just add it's `.ts` files to your source files and use them the same way you are using your code.